# log4j2 unlimited RollingFile

Tags: log4j2

I'm using log4j2 and trying to log with log-rotation. Specifically, I want to log at the maximum size of 10MB and rotate unlimitedly. The configuration below generates 3 generations of rolling files because "DefaultRolloverStrategy max" is set to 3. Could you please, guide me how to log unlimited number of files with at the maximum size of 10MB?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="format1">%m%n</Property>
        <Property name="logfile">${sys:logDirectory}/log.log</Property>
        <Property name="logfile-archive">${sys:logDirectory}/log_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
        </Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="logfile001" append="true" fileName="${logfile}"
            filePattern="${logfile-archive}">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>${format1}</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="3" />
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="logfile001" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set an **extreme** value to `DefaultRolloverStrategy max`. E.g.

```
<DefaultRolloverStrategy max="1000000000" />
```

**Update:**

According to [Log4j2 documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html), as of release 2.8, it can be done by setting `fileIndex` attribute to `nomax`. E.g.

```
<DefaultRolloverStrategy fileIndex="nomax" />
```

Comment: Thanks. Does log4j2 rotates in an unlimited way if I simply remove "DefaultRolloverStrategy" tag? I'd like to also know about it.

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Removing the "DefaultRolloverStrategy" will use the default number of files, which is 7.

Comment: @Benjamin any corresponding doc link?